# Extract data from an HTML tag which has specific attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td class="tablecontent" scope="row" rowspan="1">
        <a href="http://netprofile-us2/netprofile/npIndex.do?cpyKey=80823">ZURICH AMERICAN INSURANCE COMPANY</a>
    </td>
    <td class="tablecontent" scope="row" rowspan="1">
        FARMERS GROUP INC (14523)
    </td>
    <td class="tablecontent" scope="row">
        znaf
    </td>
    <td class="tablecontent" scope="row">
        anhm
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have an HTML document which contains multiple `tr` tags. I want to extract the `href` link from the first `td` and data from third `td` tag onwards under every `tr` tag. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you looking to get elements with specific attributes or every nth element?

Comment: i want to iterate over all tr tag and print only elements of <td> tag in the same line until i get <a> tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all `tr` elements, iterate over them, then do the context-specific searches for the inner `td` elements and get the first and the third:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cells = tr.find_all('td')
    if len(cells) < 3:
        continue  # safety pillow

    link = cells[0].a['href']  # assuming every first td has an "a" element
    data = cells[2].get_text()

    print(link, data)
```

As a side note and depending what you are trying to accomplish in the HTML parsing, I usually find [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) a great and convenient way to parse HTML tables into [dataframes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) and work with the dataframes after, which are quite convenient data structures to work with.

Comment: I think the want all from the third to the end, i.e `[td.text for td in cells[2:]`

Comment: Thanks sir for your time. Not every "tr" has "a" tag. two conditions:- first: "tr" tag start. if first "td" tag will have "a" tag then "a" tag will contain a link and "td" tag will contain text and second "td" tag might have text(but not necessary). Third "td" tag will have text. End of "tr" tag. "tr" tag starts now, it will have "td" tag but it might have "a" tag or text. i want to extract "a" tag and it's text from first "td" tag and text from third "td" tag. now if next "tr.td" tag has text then text, all in one line. if next "tr.td" tag has "a" tag then it should come in second line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector `nth-of-type` to navigate through the `td`s

Here's a sample"

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a = soup.select('td:nth-of-type(1) a')[0]
href = a['href']
td = soup.select("td:nth-of-type(3)")[0]
text = td.get_text(strip=True)
```